# Ruby thor command line tool commands

Tags: ruby, shell, rubygems, command-line-interface, thor

I am planning on making my first command line tool and was wondering about how the naming and commands work.

I would like my tool to function similarly to Git, in the sense that you just install it, then to run commands you just enter `git clone` or `git commit`. In many of the examples I have seen the tools are something like `thor foo:bar` or `./foo.rb bar`.

My main question is how can I make it so if my tools name is `Foo`, and the command in my tool is `bar`, all the user has to do is run `Foo bar` in the command line.

Comment: Where is the code that shows what you have tried, and have failed?

Comment: Like I said in the original, I have never made one of these before, and none of the resources or tutorials I have seen have showed how to do this. So there really is no try, I am really just trying to find out where to start, or just a suggestion of where I can look. I have read as much documentation as I can find on Thor and Ruby command line tools and I have found nothing.

Comment: [Here](http://rubylearning.com/blog/2011/01/03/how-do-i-make-a-command-line-tool-in-ruby/) is a blog that describes this.  It describes just plain Ruby without any help, OptParse in the Standard Library as well as an example using Thor

Comment: Thanks, I will read that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of `git clone` the way it works is that `git` program is executed and `clone` is passed to it as a parameter. So, if you have several scripts that should be started in a similar manner, you can create a small launcher. This code is in bash(but the script is `sh` compatible, so you can safely change the shebang to `/bin/sh`). It is very easy to write the same thing in any other language.

```
#!/bin/bash

command=$1
shift

case $1 in    
    cmd1)
        echo "Executing command #1"
        ./smallcmd1 "$@"
        ;;
    cmd2)
        echo "Executing command $command"
        ./smallcmd2 "$@"
        ;;
    '')
        echo 'No option specified'
        exit 1
        ;;

    *) echo "Invalid option"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
exit $?
```

Where `smallcmd`s are your secondary command scripts or programs.

Now you can execute it:

```
./mycommand smallcmd1
```

Additional parameters can be passed as well.

If you place this script into any [$PATH](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html) directory then you can omit `./` like so:

```
mycommand smallcmd1
```

Comment: Awesome, so If I wanted to have this done automatically. As in the user can just run some line to install my tool, and it works right off the bat. Is there something I change in the program to make it install to $PATH? Or does the installer command specify to put it in the $PATH? Should I make it a ruby gem possibly? It seems as though those are easy to install.

Answer (score 0):

Making an executable with Thor is really simple. All you have to do is:

- include the ruby shebang line.
- require "thor" in your script.
- define your Thor class.
- add `#{YourThorClassname}.start` to the bottom of your script.

Example: my-cli.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "thor"

class MyCLI < Thor
  desc "foo", "Prints foo"
  def foo
    puts "foo"
  end
end

MyCLI.start
```

Make the script executable:

```
chmod a+x my-cli.rb
```

Now you can type:

```
./my-cli.rb foo
```

You can find a similar example and more help in the Thor [Wiki](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/wiki/Making-An-Executable).

You can even rename the file to `my-cli` (without the `.rb` extension) and it still works because of the ruby shebang inside the file.